# Closed - Http subscribe not working on real device ionic 3

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

**Update:**
Sorry to bother everyone. Actually, the problem was with the subdomain on my local machine. That subdomain was listed in hosts file on the server but, not on the real device. That was the problem all along.

Thank you everyone who has invested time in answering. Can't mark those answers "correct" because that may misguide someone else.

### Closed

I'm trying to access some web services on my local machine which are working fine in browser. But, when I try to access the same services in real device! It doesn't call the subscribe function. I know this because I have tested it without calling the subscribe function after get or post and it works. But Observer/subscribe function or Promises are not working on real device. Below is the code I'm using for this purpose. Please help.
This piece of code:

```
var result = this.http.get('someurl for list of data');
    console.log(result);
```

works on browser and on real device also. It shows: `console.log: [object Object]` on a click of a button.
On the other hand Observer doesn't work on real device but, works in browser.

```
var res = this.http.get(this.partnersUrl).subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
    })
```

The above piece of code shows the output in browser console on click. But, doesn't show output on click from a real device. I have also tried showing a toast, which works in browser but, not in real device. Whether using `ionic cordova run android` or in ionic view or Ionic Dev app.

Ionic Info:

```
cli packages: (C:\Users\danis\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v6.11.5\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.2
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.0.1
    Node              : v6.11.5
    npm               : 3.10.10
    OS                : Windows 10

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\danis\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Ionic plugins list:

```
cordova-plugin-add-swift-support 1.7.1 "AddSwiftSupport"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device"
cordova-plugin-ionic 2.0.4 "IonicCordova"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.1.16 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.ionic.starter" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Some app</name>
    <description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="1.1.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~4.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^1.1.11" />
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
    <engine name="android" spec="~6.3.0" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8100" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.0.10:8100" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic" spec="^2.0.4">
        <variable name="APP_ID" value="84027630" />
        <variable name="CHANNEL_NAME" value="Master" />
        <variable name="UPDATE_METHOD" value="background" />
        <variable name="UPDATE_API" value="https://api.ionicjs.com" />
        <variable name="MAX_STORE" value="2" />
    </plugin>
</widget>
```

I can't move forward until this issue is resolved. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The request may be failing on the device, but there is no way to know, since you are not using the `error` handler. Try the following:

```
var res = this.http.get(this.partnersUrl).subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
    }, error => {console.log("error", error});
```

Comment: I'm using the error handler already. But, didn't post it in the example above.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue a couple weeks ago, what fixed it for me was to delete the cordova-plugin-ionic-webview plugin.

`cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-ionic-webview`

Comment: **This is not a solution**. The old `UIWebView` is deprecated and using it will cause a lot of issues/bugs when running the app on iOS